# Is it possible to restore centralManager state after application is updated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, core-bluetooth

I am working on one application in which I need to support continuous background app execution. I am able to communicate continuously using Apple's available background modes. But facing one issue when application is in background (or not running) and install an updated version of app, after that, centralManager delegates have stopped functioning. So I am not sure whether can We restore CentralManager state after app update or not ??

If its not possible then is there any other option(or patch ;) ) available ??

One alternate way is to send silent push notification to start the application run in background (But for this, we have to send silent notification as soon as new app version is installed on all the devices)..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Centeral manager's information will be restored if it lost its handle when it goes to suspend state.

If application falls down to suspend mode then it's going to be lost its memory and at this time the system keeps application's BLE information to restore the information when the application comes up in foreground.

But not sure when application gets update...